# Changing IdentityUser Type in ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I want my `User` to have a `Guid` as the primary key, but when I create my own user type, my website throws an exception on startup.

Anyone knows how to change IdentityUser type?

I did this:

```
services.AddIdentity<MyUser, MyRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UBContext>()
    .AddDefaultUI()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

But when my program starts up I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: No service for type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'
>   has been registered.

Does that have something to do with the fact that the identity UI is now in a separate lib and a controller in that lib is expecting a `UserManager<IdentityUser>`?

How can I override that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, so found the problem.  _LoginPartial.cshtml injects

```
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser>
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser>
```

so you need to make sure that they are updated to

```
@inject SignInManager<MyUser>
@inject UserManager<MyUser>
```

Comment: Good spot, didnt notice this had been scaffolded in and was part of the _layout

Answer (score 1):

You should extend the `IdentityUser` from your `MyUser` class:

```
public class MyUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Then registering the new user class:

`services.AddIdentity<MyUser , MyRole>()`

And finally, where your `UserManager` is injected, add your own type:

`public HomeController(UserManager<MyUser> userManager) { }`